# Set custom label for APA bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm writing a document with `biblatex` bibliography, using the APA style. For some entries I need a label different from the automatic, so I specify it with `shorthand` field. But it looks like the shorthand is ignored and the label is generated automatically instead.

Here's a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
    @book{doe,
        author          = {Doe, John},
        title           = {A very good book},
        date            = {2000},
    }
    
    @online{foo,
        title           = {Foo Bar},
        url             = {https://example.com},
        shorthand       = {foo},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{doe}
    
    \cite{foo}
\end{document}
```

With this I expect

> Doe, 2000
>
> foo

but instead I get

> Doe, 2000
>
> “Foo Bar”, n.d.

How I can set the label I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `apa` style is a conforming APA7 style, and I suspect that the APA doesn't support this sort of citation. So perhaps you should work with one of the more generic author-year styles, like `ext-authoryear` which will likely support the `shorthand` field.

Comment: @AlanMunn In my `apa.cbx` there are some lines and comments that look like supporting `shorthand`, e.g. `% Cite using shorthand` `{\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}`. But I don't know much about biblatex, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @FoonatanBarrer The line you quote is only for `\textcite` and not `\cite` (and won't give the format you show in your question, instead it will print `Foo Bar [foo]`). Of course you can redefine the bib macros to give the format you want, but will this still be apa conform?

Comment: I'm the author of the APA style and it's quite complicated and specific and so not very customisable (because then it wouldn't be APA style ...). Generally you are better off taking a generic style and changing it with options or code modifications/patches as the generic styles are designed to be more customisable.